Fix position of the dropdown menu in VUE.js under the icon you click on
As a project I am designing the frontend of an application to log in and select the possible tabs on a web page. Additionally, there's an icon, which is considered to be an avatar. When clicked, a dropdown menu should appear. However after implementing the code, taking into account that the whole list with locations of the tabs is also in the container, our dropdown menu seems to keep appearing on the left, rather than under the icon. I already tried to align better and change the html class types but nothing worked so far.
The code can be seen below.

TEMPLATE CODE

<template>
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar>
      <v-app-bar-nav-icon
        class="hidden-sm-and-up"
        @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"
      ></v-app-bar-nav-icon>

      <v-container> <!-- class="fill-height d-flex align-center" -->
        <span
          v-for="link in navigation_links"
          :key="link.name"
        >
          <v-btn
            class="hidden-xs"
            v-if="checkRoles(link.allowedRoles)"
            :key="link.name"
            :prepend-icon="link.icon"
            :to="link.location"
          >
            {{ link.name }}
          </v-btn>
        </span>
      </v-container>
      <v-menu
        v-model="menuOpen"
        :close-on-content-click="false"
        :nudge-right="40"
        transition="scale-transition"
        offset-y
      >
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
          <v-btn @click="menuOpen = !menuOpen" icon v-on="on">
            <v-icon>mdi-account</v-icon>
          </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-item @click="navigateTo('/profile')">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-card-account-details</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>View profile</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-divider></v-divider>
          <v-list-item @click="themeStore.toggleTheme()">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-theme-light-dark</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Dark mode on/off</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="navigateTo('/help')">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-help-box</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Help</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item @click="showLogoutConfirmationDialog">
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-logout</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Logout</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </v-app-bar>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      class="hidden-sm-and-up"
      v-model="drawer"
      temporary
    >
      <v-list
        :lines="false"
        density="compact"
        nav
      >
        <span
          v-for="link in navigation_links"
          :key="link.name"
        >
          <v-list-item
            v-if="checkRoles(link.allowedRoles)"
            :key="link.name"
            :title="link.name"
            :to="link.location"
            :prepend-icon="link.icon"
            active-color="primary"
          >
          </v-list-item>
        </span>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

    <v-main :class="theme.global.current.value.dark ? 'black': 'bg-grey-lighten-3'">
      <v-container>
        <v-sheet
          min-height="70vh"
          rounded="lg"
        >
          <RouterView/>
        </v-sheet>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>

    <v-dialog v-model="logoutConfirmationDialog" max-width="500">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title class="headline">Logout Confirmation</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>
          Are you sure you want to log out?
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="logout">Yes</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="secondary" @click="logoutConfirmationDialog = false">Go Back</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-app>
</template>


script

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {useTheme} from 'vuetify'
import {ref} from "vue";
import {useAuthStore} from "@/stores/AuthStore";
import {useThemeStore} from "@/stores/ThemeStore";
import config from "../../config";
import router from "@/router";

const theme = useTheme()
const themeStore = useThemeStore()
const authStore = useAuthStore()
const drawer = ref(false)
const navigation_links = config["NAVIGATION"]
const menuOpen = ref(false)
const logoutConfirmationDialog = ref(false)

function checkRoles(roles: string[]): boolean {
  const intersection = authStore.userInfo?.roles.filter(element => roles.includes(element));
  if (!intersection) {
    return false
  }
  return intersection.length > 0
}

function activateDropdown(){
  menuOpen.value = true;
}

function logout() {
  // Handle logout
  console.log('Logout clicked!');
  authStore.logout(); // Actually log out the user
  logoutConfirmationDialog.value = false; // Close the dialog after logout
}

function navigateTo(route: any) {
  // Navigate to the specified route
  console.log('Navigating to:', route);
  router.push(route);
  // You can use your preferred routing library to navigate, for example:
  // this.$router.push(route);
}

function showLogoutConfirmationDialog() {
  logoutConfirmationDialog.value = true;
}
</script>


RESULT


